# Cannot hide a element in javascript using onfocus event

Tags: javascript, html

when i trying to hide the element div while click on text box using javascript.but it can't.what is the error on my program .anyone suggest me a good one

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script>
   function clear()
   {
    alert("hi");
    document.getElementById("mails").style.display="none";
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
  <input type="text" onfocus="clear();" />
  <div id="mails">hii</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: assuming suggesting a "good one" is some sort if Indian saying, it's now removed. If it was something related to your code, please write it more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using function name as clear(), please use any other name.
clear method refers to obsolete document.clear() method so it does not call clear method written by you.
According to [HTML5 Specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-clear), clear() method must do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

IT's very easy to hide elements if you use jQuery. This way, all you need to do is:

```
$('#mails').hide();
```

---

If you prefer using DOM, then you can try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
   function hideit()
   {
    alert("hi");
    document.getElementById("mails").style.display="none";
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" onClick="hideit()" />
  <div id="mails">hii</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, should work now. the clear() can't be used. use an own name.

Answer (score 1):

Though clear is not a keyword but it seems some browser still supports [document.clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear) & that may be stopping the clear function here . You can change the function name and try

```js
function myF() {
  
  document.getElementById("mails").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="myF();" />
<div id="mails">hii</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am to late but nevertheless I can agree brk. The clear() is blocked by a native function.

```html
<html>
   <head>
   <script>
     function clearFunction()
     {
       console.log("onfocus called");
       document.getElementById("mails").style.display="none";   
     }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <input type="text" onfocus="clearFunction();" />
    <div id="mails">hii</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The code that fixes the problem should be inside the answer itself as links can rot and potentially go away. Also fyi your fiddle doesn't work because you still have `onfocus="clear()"`